# JavaFX: How not to fill background outside the rounded borders of a Label within a ScrollingPane

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'm trying to get rounded borders on a Label inside a ScrollingPane, but the background fill of the Label still appears as a rectangle even though the borders are rounded. How do I make sure that the background fill conforms to the rounded borders of the Label?

[image: Fills outside of rounded borders]

Java:

```
String quizMetaData = quiz.getQuizMetadata();

Label quizInfoText = new Label(quizMetaData);
ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();

quizInfoText.setId("quiz-info-text");
quizInfoText.prefWidthProperty().bind(scrollPane.widthProperty().multiply(0.95));
quizInfoText.prefHeightProperty().bind(scrollPane.heightProperty().multiply(0.98));

scrollPane.setContent(quizInfoText);
scrollPane.setId("quiz-info-scrollpane");
scrollPane.setPrefSize(600, 250);
scrollPane.setLayoutX(100);
scrollPane.setLayoutY(60);
pane.getChildren().add(scrollPane);
```

CSS:

```
#quiz-info-text {
    -fx-background-color: #203020;
    -fx-font: 16pt "Courier New";
    -fx-text-fill: #00C030;
    -fx-alignment: top-center;
    -fx-border-width: 10;
    -fx-border-color: #306030;
    -fx-border-radius: 15.0;
    -fx-padding: 1;
    -fx-wrap-text: true;
}

#quiz-info-text:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #304030;
    -fx-font: 16pt "Courier New";
    -fx-text-fill: #00E020;
    -fx-alignment: top-center;
    -fx-border-width: 10;
    -fx-border-color: #306030;
    -fx-border-radius: 15.0;
    -fx-padding: 1;
    -fx-wrap-text: true;
}

#quiz-info-scrollpane {
    -fx-background: #000000;
    -fx-fit-to-width: true;
    -fx-fit-to-height: false;
    -fx-vbar-policy: as-needed;
    -fx-hbar-policy: as-needed;
    -fx-border-color: #000000;
    -fx-background-color: black;
}

#quiz-info-scrollpane:focused {
    -fx-border-color: #000000;
    -fx-background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: Did you try matching `-fx-background-radius` to `-fx-border-radius`? See also the [JavaFX CSS Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks @sillyfly for pointing out -

I've forgotten to add `-fx-background-radius: 15` in the CSS!

Answer (score 0):

Set background color of label transparent

```
-fx-background-color: transparent;
```

Comment: this was not what i was looking for, as I still wanted the background color